# Searchkick not working with whitepace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

so i have this searckick method:

```
search_options = {
  misspellings: { edit_distance: 2 },
  fields: [:eventname, :date, :city],
  order: { _score: :desc, date: :asc, eventname: :asc, city: :asc },
  match: :word_start,
  suggest: true,
  page: params[:page],
  per_page: 20
}
if params[:date_from].present?
  datefrom = params[:date_from].to_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  dateto = params[:date_to].to_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  search_options[:where] =  { date: {gte: datefrom, lte: dateto} }
end
```

This isn't working with whitespaces.... e.g. `bassjam` isn't matching `bass jam`

any ideas why?

Sam

Comment: Just to clarify, with this setup searching `bass jam` does return the expected results?

Comment: Yes it does, It returns a full set of different results.

Comment: Not a possible duplicate, but an exact copy.